# icinga2 multi instance display

Tags: monitoring, icinga

i have ~30 independent icinga2 systems. All have their own config.
Not i am locking for a dashboard showing problems off all nodes.

I tryed to setup a master server where i add those nodes.
when i do:

```
icinga2 node list

Node 'portal-sta' (last seen: Thu Dec 17 14:44:22 2015)
    * Host 'BH060'
        * Service 'Ping'
```

I get my nodes and all the services on cli.
But icingaweb2 dont display them.

Is there a solution to hava a dashboard (with force check and acknowledge?) without central configuration?

Or is there a better software for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use "node list" and "node update-config" to generate the objects on the master. Reloading the daemon will populate your central Icinga Web 2 using the DB IDO backend. Once you acknowledge, add a comment or schedule a downtime for these objects, these events are replicated to the satellite nodes and will be executed over there as well.